# Active nav pill to have same color as info button

Tags: bootstrap-4

The active nav pills by default have `primary` color. How can I elegantly apply `info` color?

```
<nav className="nav flex-column nav-pills">
  <a className="nav-link active" href="#">Dashboard</a>
  <a className="nav-link" href="#">Apps</a>
</nav>
```

This is is how the nav bar looks.

[image]

I want the color of active pill to be `info`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reference the `info` CSS variable like this...

```
.nav-pills .nav-link.active {
    background-color: var(--info);
}
```

[Demo](https://www.codeply.com/go/YcjV723ITU)

***Or***, using SASS...

```
@import "bootstrap/functions";
@import "bootstrap/variables";

$nav-pills-link-active-bg: theme-color("info");

@import "bootstrap";
```

[Demo 2](https://www.codeply.com/go/PxEYAutPmR)